# FullText Search Only Displays 1 result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

I'm outputting results for a search query, but for some reason, it's not outputting more than one result.
It may be, because i'm tired but anyone spot the mistake i'm making?

All i want it to do, is search my database with the inputted word from the search bar and find all matches or close matches of the input.

Am i missing something?

```
$search = $_POST['search'];

// We preform a bit of filtering 

$filtered = mysql_real_escape_string($search);

//Select what add to look for.
$ad_type = $_POST[''];

 //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM busadverts WHERE MATCH(advert_name, advert_description, advert_tags) AGAINST('". $filtered ."  IN BOOLEAN MODE')"; 

 $result = mysql_Query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
//And we display the results 

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
 { 

 $adname = $row['advert_name'];
 $adimage = $row['advert_image'];
 $addesc = $row['advert_description'];
 $adurl = $row['advert_url'];

 $searchresult .= "<div style='width: 800px; height: 200px;'>
<div class='titleBar' style='text-align: center; background: #000; color: #fff;'>"
. $adname . "
</div>
<div class='advertimage' style='width: 150px; height: 150px; float: left; background: #111;text-align: center;'> 
<img src='" . $adimage . "' /> 
</div>
<div class='advertdescription' style='width: 635px; height: 150px; float: left;  background: #222;color: #fff; padding-left: 15px;'>Description: <br />"
. $addesc ." 
<br /><br /> Website link: <a href='" .$adurl."'>" 
. $adurl . "</a>
</div>

</div>"; 

} 

 //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little  message explaining that 
$anymatches=mysql_num_rows($result); 
if ($anymatches == 0) 
{ 
echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
} 



   mysql_free_result($result); 

//And we remind them what they searched for 
echo "<b>Results: </b> " .$search. "" ; 
echo $searchresult;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Also noticed, it doesn't pull out everything e.g "test" seems to pull Testing or Test or test but if i was to put "Test" as the search term, it only displays items with capital letters, for this would it best to just strttolow all searches?

Comment: I can't find anything wrong- are you sure there are more than one matching row? Where do you initiate `$searchresult`? Maybe you need to do that outside the while loop?

Comment: I have 2 rows containing Swindon, in its description or title, one that says "Swindon" and the other that says "swindon" but only one will show.

Comment: Also the code is in a function and outputted to the page called by.
    <?php 
    include "includes/common.php";
    search_ads("");
    ?>

Comment: Ahh it does output more than one, but they have to be the same, it wont select multiple types, e.g. test has to be test and Test has to be Test. Any ideas on how to make this so i can work with all varied types of typing the selected word?

Comment: How many rows are in the table you are searching on? If it's a low number, it could be the "found the word in at least 50% of the posts so lets discard it as a common word" problem with fulltext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search against anything that includes the word `test` you should use `*` as wildcard

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM busadverts WHERE MATCH(advert_name, advert_description, advert_tags) AGAINST('*". $filtered ."*'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Also, it looks like your `'` apostrophe was off in the `Against` section.